# Sink drain piping, smelly and trap isn't dry

Tags: plumbing, drain, smell, p-trap

I recently installed a new sink and had to redo all the drain pipes.  There is a pretty bad sewer gas smell coming from the drain.  It is a kitchen sink so it gets used frequently.  I checked the trap and there was water in there.  In the picture the other pipe that goes to the right is the air vent from the basement bathroom plumbing.  I am stumped what is wrong, did I install something improperly.  An ideas are appreciated.[image]

Comment: If the pipe coming from the right is a vent from other plumbing, is that not feeding smelly air to the sink above the trap? (Ie should it not be connected after the trap?)

Comment: I should have been a little clearer.  It is a double sink the pipe to the right is for the other drain.  The pipe coming from the basement is in the top of the picture way back going to the right.  And it is connected in after the trap.

Comment: There has been times where the right side drain has a smell, but not the left.  If the glued pvc connections are glued, but not completely seated could that cause the smell.  Could a trap somehow dry out after only a few hours.

Comment: Oh boy, you did yourself no favors whatsoever by gluing that trap into place!

Comment: How is this vented? Is it an AAV (replace) or an actual piped vent to the roof (clean)? If the right sink smells, specifically, suspect improper slope on the right to left pipe causing stuff to sit in it and rot, rather than being drained away.

Answer (score 1):

Among other concerns, it looks like the trap adapter is installed on the wrong side of the trap and attached to the tailpiece.  You should check if food is getting stuck in the top of the adapter.